# I am trying to get blog from ghostCMS into Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, ghost-blog

I have a ghost server then I have one with sveltekit. In my ghost, I have made site private so i can only access via API. I have set up intergration and recieved API token. When i try the sample code in the documentation I dont manage to get posts in. I am not sure what I am missing. Th SDK gives an error in my code when I try import it.

Here is code:

```js
<script context='module'>
import GhostContentAPI from '@tryghost/content-api';
// const GhostContentAPI = require('@tryghost/content-api');


const GHOST_URL = 'http://blog.nafuna.tv';
const GHOST_KEY = '87f6096411ae42f96df2615620';
const GHOST_VERSION = 'v4';

export async function load() {
  const api = GhostContentAPI({
      url: GHOST_URL,
      key: GHOST_KEY,
      version: GHOST_VERSION})
  const postsJson = await api.posts.browse({limit: 5, include: 'tags,authors'});

  return {
    props: {
      postsJson: postsJson
    }
  }
}


</script>

<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    // export let postsJson; 
    export let data: PageData;
</script>
```

This doesn't give me any luck and even after i installed the sdk i get this error:
[image]

Comment: Adding a bit more to the thread. I still haven't got it to work but I tried a different way of loading the data into the page and I still get an error 500:

Comment: You can check this article https://www.patrick-segarel.com/blog/building-a-blog-with-sveltekit-and-ghost-cms, there's also a link to a repo with a simple working implementation, using the content api to retrieve posts & pages

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, working with Svelte v3.59, TypeScript v5.04, TryGhost/content-api v1.11, @types/TryGhost v1.3.11

+layout.ts

```js
import GhostContentAPI from '@tryghost/content-api';

/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */
export async function load() {
    const GHOST_URL = 'https://ghost.address';
    const GHOST_KEY = 'authentication_key';
    const GHOST_VERSION = 'v5.0';

    const api = GhostContentAPI({
        url: GHOST_URL,
        key: GHOST_KEY,
        version: GHOST_VERSION
    });

    try {
        const postsJson = await api.posts.browse({limit: 5, include: ['tags', 'authors']});

        return {
            posts: postsJson.map((post) => ({
                title: post.title? post.title : 'No title',
                slug: post.slug!,
                updated_at: post.updated_at!,
                feature_image: post.feature_image? post.feature_image : 'https://ghost.address/placeholder.png',
                feature_image_alt: post.feature_image_alt? post.feature_image_alt : '',
                excerpt: post.excerpt? post.excerpt : '',
                tags: post.tags!.map(tag => tag.name),
                authors: post.authors?.map(author => author.name) || ['Unknown author'],
            })),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

This data is passed to
+page.svelte (can be +layout.svelte aswell)

```
<script>
    import Post from "$lib/components/Post.svelte";
    export let data;
</script>

{#each data.posts ?? [] as post}
    <Post {...post} />
{/each}
```

and as you can see, it is presented by Post components
Post.svelte

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let title: string,
        slug: string,
        feature_image: string,
        feature_image_alt: string,
        updated_at: string,
        tags: (string | undefined)[],
        authors: string[],
        excerpt: string;

    const date = new Date(updated_at);
    const time = date.toLocaleTimeString('pl-PL', {
        day: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        year: 'numeric',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit'
    });
</script>

<a id="post" data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover" href={`/blog/${slug}`}>
    <img loading="lazy" src={feature_image} alt={feature_image_alt} />
    <div id="post-text">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p id="post-text-p">{@html excerpt}</p>
        <div id="info">
        {#each authors as author}
            <p>{author}</p>
        {/each}
            <p>{time}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```